# How make a route with 2 or more "slug" ? (React-Router-Dom)

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I asking this question because i create an back-office and some component make the same thing but not in the same API route.

For example i have 4 theme:
*-History
-Actuality
-Product
-Method*

In each theme i have 4 method :
*-create
-modify
-delete
-getAll$*

how make a route with react-router-dom like :

**path='/:theme/:method/:id' component={???}**

For exemple, actualy i have some route like :

```
<Router>
    <Header />
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/all-products" component={AllProducts} />
      <Route exact path="/create-product" component={CreateProduct} />
      <Route exact path="/product" component={Product} />
      <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
      <Route exact path="/modify/product/:id" component={ModifyProduct} />
      <Route exact path="/delete/product" component={DeleteProduct} />
      <Route
        exact
        path="/delete/product/:id"
        component={DeleteConfirmation}
      />

      <Route exact path="/actuality" component={Actuality} />
      <Route exact path="/create-actuality" component={CreateActuality} />
      <Route exact path="/all-actuality" component={AllActuality} />
      <Route
        exact
        path="/modify/actuality/:id"
        component={ModifyActuality}
      />
      <Route exact path="/delete/actuality" component={DeleteActuality} />
      <Route
        exact
        path="/delete/actuality/:id"
        component={DeleteActualityConfirmation}
      />

      <Route exact path="/history" component={History} />
      <Route exact path="/create-history" component={CreateHistory} />
      <Route exact path="/all-history" component={AllHistory} />
      <Route exact path="/modify/history/:id" component={ModifyHistory} />
      <Route exact path="/delete/history" component={DeleteHistory} />
      <Route
        exact
        path="/delete/history/:id"
        component={DeleteHistoryConfirmation}
      />

      <Route exact path="/method" component={Method} />
      <Route exact path="/create-method" component={CreateMethod} />
      <Route exact path="/all-method" component={AllMethod} />
      <Route exact path="/modify/method/:id" component={ModifyMethod} />
      <Route exact path="/delete/method" component={DeleteMethod} />
      <Route
        exact
        path="/delete/method/:id"
        component={DeleteMethodConfirmation}
      />
    </Switch>
  </Router>
```

And yes i want to refact my code ^^.

Comment: Instead of using the [theme]-[method] as a pathname, why not just include the pathname as 1 liner? For example for ```/create-history``` you could just set is as ```/history/create``` same goes for ```/actuality/create``` which are pretty self-explanatory and they also make sense for their scope. You can do conditional rendering based on theme name.

Comment: Yes ! That's true but can i make something like : */:theme/:method/ (if needed) :id* ? I want to make a route to rule them all. or two one with id and an other without